# Joining a Chord network (dht)

Tags: networking, distributed-computing, dht, chord

I'm writing a chord netowrk on my LAN (the node key is an hash of the IP)
I read many articles about Chord network
but I didn't figure it out:
when a new client want to join the network, it must know another client in the network
or some kind of server to manage a new client joining.

am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when joining a DHT network, you must know at least one other node in the network you can announce yourself to.

Comment: Even if we knew one random node in the network, How can we form a finger table? Because the hash of that node ip+port might not correspond to the hash ids of the finger table.

Comment: Eg : - If first node of the network has hash id = 1, Then second node has to know the first node inorder to join the network. Let assume hash id of second node = 4. First node finger table should have hash ids 2,3,5,9,... But second node hash is 4. Then how is forming chord network is possible? I'm really lost when I began to implement it. @dande